# Typo3 with Bootstrap package: How to change the padding of main content column

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, typo3, padding

I am administrating the homepage of our local sports club which can be found under [svwalddorf.de](https://svwalddorf.de)
The page runs with typo3 10.4.22 with bootstrap package 11.0.3.

The basic template of bootstrap leaves a lot of empty space on each side of the centered content area
[On our site this currently looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu9Bh.jpg) (unfortunately not allowed to include images yet)

While this looks pretty nice, it wastes a lot of space. Therefore, I would like to change the size of the padding areas (marked red) to have more room for content.

I am pretty sure that I just need to find the right line in the correct css file. After all, the grey carousel element near the top uses the entire width. I just do not know what to look for.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It is the .container { max-width: 1200px; } probably?

Comment: It's not only padding but the container/content-width. If you wanna change from a fixed-width-layout to a fluid-width-layout, you have to care about much more, than just removing the padding... With inner content/box should/must also change its behavior? Are the generate images matching the display-width of each user? Is a fluid layout compatible/useful for a 49" display?...  A good entrypoint seems to be the Bootstrap 4 documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

Answer (score 0):

There is a map in SCSS that contains the maximum widths of the container for each breakpoint defined in the $grid-breakpoints variable. You can set the values for this map using TypoScript, like so:

```
plugin.bootstrap_package.settings.scss {
   container-max-widths= (  sm: 540px,  md: 720px,  lg: 960px,  xl: 1140px,  xxl: 1320px)
}
```

The $grid-breakpoints variable defines the breakpoints and their corresponding widths:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (  xs: 0,  sm: 576px,  md: 768px,  lg: 992px,  xl: 1200px,  xxl: 1400px )
```

To increase the size of the container, you have two options. You can either set the max-width property directly on the container class, like this:

```
.container { max-width: 80%; }
```

My recommendation is, to update the values in the container-max-widths map to set different maximum widths for each breakpoint:

```
container-max-widths= (  sm: 540px,  md: 720px,  lg: 992px,  xl: 1200px,  xxl: 1400px)
```

Just make sure not to set values higher than those defined in $grid-breakpoints.

Look at:

- https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/1449d02038bd19aa697650f937c01cb917e509e3/Resources/Public/Contrib/bootstrap5/scss/_variables.scss
- https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/1449d02038bd19aa697650f937c01cb917e509e3/Resources/Public/Contrib/bootstrap5/scss/_containers.scss